# Flutter Project build in macOS

Tags: flutter

I am windows user and have no experience with macOS. I have developed flutter app in Windows 10 using Android Studio. All working fine and already tested with physical Android Device. Now it is the time to test IOS device. There's the problem started.

I can't build my project in XCode. I already changed user defined build settings as shown in screenshots

[image]

When build the project, it is still finding the flutter SDK location of `Windows OS`
[image]

This is my flutter doctor check in macOS
[image]

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with the help of my friend - flutter developer.

1. Go to the project directory and run `flutter create -i swift .` It will recreate the ios folder in project.
2. Then run `pod install` command under ios folder